# Problem with sizing lightning-input with type date LWC Salesforce Mobile

Tags: css, salesforce, salesforce-lightning, lwc

[mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0jSE.png)
When I try to change size the field using styles etc. visually everything is fine, but only the first part of the field is active. This problem occurs only on the mobile version and with the type="date", any other options work fine(type="text", desktop version).

```
<lightning-input
   required
   type="date"
   lang="en_gb"
   label={labels.testDate}
   value={data.testDate}
   data-name="testDate"
   data-validation-name="datafield"
   onchange={handleDataChange}
 >
</lightning-input>
```

I use custom css classes, style="width: 100%", width: 500px and etc.